# My Mouse lags on HDD Activity after Ubuntu 19.10 Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, dma

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10. But after upgrade I noticed that my mouse starts lagging while doing file transfers or any hard drive activity.

Can anyone explain why is this happening and how to fix it?

Please help, I am not able to run any virtual machines properly.